# Running a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.6.2

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

- I have a docker deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - http://paymentsystem-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/ . The application is Java web application .
- It runs about one day and then I get a 502 Bad Gateway from nginx/1.6.2.
- \var\log\nginx\access.log & \var\log\nginx\error.log are empty.
- Dockerrun.aws.json :

```html
{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
  "Name": "kazenguyen/paymentsystem:v1",
  "Update": "true"
 },
 "Ports": [
 {
  "ContainerPort": "8080"
 }
 ]
}
```

The nginx logs don't show anything.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Root cause:**
- Choose EC instance (t1.micro) is not enough memory to run my webapp, so Glassfish crashes.

**Soloution:**
- Choose EC instance (c1.xlarge) which is more memory than t1.micro.